# AWS s3 allow access for specific website and block other requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi how would i create a bucket policy that allows a specific website but restricts all other requests.Other requests eed to be authentiacte by an IAM role

say my website is http://53.3.xx.xx/

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Did you look at using CloudFront and Signed URLs?

Comment: I would have to sign the url on every request it seemed unnecessary thats why i asked about bucket policy

Comment: You can create a policy that allows access to objects if the request `Referer` header matches.  It's not secure, it's just a way to stop hotlinking from other sites.  If you want security, you need something different.  What's the use case?